# How can I get user+sys returned from time?

Tags: bash

I would like to use time to benchmark some code. It seems user+sys is the right measure. But is it possible to get this output as a single number rather than having to add them by hand?

Comment: The GNU man page  (if you're using the GNU version of time) shows you how to use a format string to produce an expression that you can evaluate. However, you may be more interested in getting the duration (real) of the code instead of CPU consumption. After all, a user feels a program's duration more than a user feels CPU consumption.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the documentation of bash's built in `time` (see `help time`) and GNU time (see `man time`) it seems like it is impossible to add those numbers up directly.

You have to manually add the numbers. Here we use GNU `time` instead of the built-in because it offers the `-o` option.

```
 command time -f %S+%U -o >(bc -l) yourCommandHere
```

The last line of the output will be the sum of user time and system time in seconds.  `command` ensures that the binary `time` (usually `/usr/bin/time`) is used instead of the bash's built-in `time`. `bc -l` adds up the numbers printed by `time`. As the numbers are floating point we cannot use bash built-ins to do this job.*

* Well, actually you could use bash built-ins when resorting to some hacks:

```
TIMEFORMAT='10#%3U+10#%3S'
t=$( { time yourCommandHere; } 2>&1 >/dev/null)
printf -v t %04d "$((${t//./}))"
echo "${t:: -3}.${t: -3}"
```

Comment: The built-in `time` does support custom format strings -- just with different usage from the external version. Not an objection -- this is a perfectly reasonable answer -- just a note that one _could_ use either implementation to achieve the desired effect.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thank you for the notice. I totally overlooked the environment variable `TIMEFORMAT` in search for an option like `-f`.